# How to fix this problem when generating a pseudorandom number in Python?

Tags: python, random, time, hash

```
import hashlib
import time
def random():
    hashtime = str(int(time.time() * (10 ** 6)))
    encoded = hashlib.new("sha3_512", hashtime.encode())
    decoded = int(encoded.hexdigest(), 16)
    
    dcsmall = decoded / (10 ** (len(str(decoded))))
    return (dcsmall)
```

I tried this code to simulate the function random.random() without the module random. I wanted to generate a random number between 0 and 1 but this code doesn't output numbers between 0 and 0.1 because of the length of "decoded" and I have no idea how to fix it.
Please don't make huge changes to my code but instead give me an idea how to solve the problem.
Thank you

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, but can't you simplify your code to `decoded = int(encoded.hexdigest(), 16)`? `hexdigest` already returns a `string`.

Comment: Yes, I can do that. Thank you for this tip.

Comment: Don't use `len(str(decoded))`. Figure out the maximum possible length of `decoded`, and use that instead.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work because the hexadecimal length is fixed but the decimal length isn't and so it varies between 152 and 155. But if I set it to 155, I only get numbers below 0.2.

Comment: Fyi: `import math` and then `math.log(2 ** 512, 10)` yields `154.12735777995834`.

Comment: You're better off using the methods of the [Random class of the random module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) after supplying the class with an appropriate seed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do it:

```
import hashlib
import time

def random():
    hashtime = str(int(time.time() * (10 ** 6)))
    encoded = hashlib.new("sha3_512", hashtime.encode())
    decoded = int(encoded.hexdigest(), 16)
    
    dcsmall = decoded / (2 ** 512)
    return (dcsmall)
```

SHA3-512 hashes are 512 bits long – no need to worry about how long they are in decimal or hexadecimal notation.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now as I see it, it is really obvious.

Answer (score 1):

There is a discrepancy between the range of your decode value and the denominator of your division.  One is a binary value and the other is decimal based.  The potential range of the resulting fraction cannot be 0...1 because the maximum value of `decode` does not match the length of its string representation in number of digits.

What you need to do is take a chunk of the value where you can force or determine the minimum and maximum range of `decode`.  I would suggest using a modulo of the `decode` value and use the same denominator to obtain a 0...1 fraction:

```
dcsmall = decoded%2**64 / 2**64
```